# Closed form lasso solution with side constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Consider the follwing optimization model known as the lasso problem for which a closed-form solution exists, see [Derivation of closed-form lasso solution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17781/derivation-of-closed-form-lasso-solution/291421).

Lasso: $$\min_\beta \quad (Y-X\beta)^T(Y-X\beta) + \lambda \|\beta\|_1 $$

Now consider a closely related optimization problem as

$$\min_\beta \quad (Y-X\beta)^T(Y-X\beta) + \lambda \|\beta\|_1 $$

$$\beta_i \leq t_i \quad \forall i \in \{1, ..., p\}$$.

where $t_i$ is a known constant.

Can we derive a closed form solution for this problem?

Comment: The "closed form solution" you've referred to is limited to the case where $X$ has orthonormal columns which isn't very common.

Comment: Thanks. Thus, the second problem does not have a closed form solution, in general.